# Is switch with strings more than just syntactic sugar?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

Since Java 1.7, strings can be used with switch statements, which has me wondering about something. `switch` statements on integer values be turned into jump tables, which are faster than simply doing `if` checks on integers calculated at runtime; can a similar optimization be done with strings or is this just syntactic sugar?

Comment: `String` switch seems to be implemented using a fixed size map resulting in logarithmic performance for small numbers of items. See http://java-performance.info/string-switch-performance/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes switch with string is a syntatic sugar. From [here](http://java67.blogspot.in/2013/12/strings-in-switch-case-java-7-tutorial.html)

> 1) Strings in Switch are syntactic sugar, no change in JVM level.
>
> 2) Internally it uses equals method to compare, which means, if you
>   pass null it will throw java.lang.NullPointerException, so beware of
>   that.
>
> 3) Strings in switch statements are case sensitive, prefer to use only
>   one case and convert input to preferred case before passing them to
>   switch statement.

Also check **[How String in Switch works in Java 7](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/05/how-string-in-switch-works-in-java-7.html)**

From the same link if you see the example:

```
public class StringInSwitchCase{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String mode = args[0]; switch (mode) { 
            case "ACTIVE": System.out.println("Application is running on Active mode"); 
                break; 
            case "PASSIVE": System.out.println("Application is running on Passive mode"); 
                break; 
           case "SAFE": System.out.println("Application is running on Safe mode"); 
        } } }
```

and the Decompiled Code :

```
import java.io.PrintStream; 
public class StringInSwitchCase{ 
    public StringInSwitchCase() { } 
    public static void main(string args[]) { 
        String mode = args[0]; String s; 
        switch ((s = mode).hashCode()) { 
            default: break; 
            case -74056953: if (s.equals("PASSIVE")) { 
                System.out.println("Application is running on Passive mode"); } 
                break; 
            case 2537357: if (s.equals("SAFE")) { System.out.println("Application is running on Safe mode"); }
                break; 
            case 1925346054: if (s.equals("ACTIVE")) { System.out.println("Application is running on Active mode"); } 
                break; } } }
```

you will find out that String in Switch works by using `hashCode()` and `equals()` method.

> **As expected it uses hashCode() method for switching and equals()
>   method for verification, This means it's just a syntactic sugar,
>   rather than an inbuilt native functionality.**

Comment: The last two statements in there strike me as contradictory: is the difference in byte code efficiency really that big if it requires you to create a new, lower/uppercase string in order to use it?

Comment: So... if the byte code is more efficient, then they are not exactly syntactic sugar.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel:- Yes thats contradictory. I removed that part and add the code to make it more clear.

Comment: Perhaps there I am getting hung up on what one means by syntactic sugar. Autoboxing is syntactic sugar (it simply infers a method call). Varargs is syntactic sugar (it infers array creation). This is a bit more complicated. The compiler calculates the hash value and builds case statement. If 2 conditions have same hash code, you get an if/else/else if statement. That feels like a bit more than simple syntactic sugar.

Comment: Syntactic sugar is something the compiler does for you instead of you writing it out by hand. In this case, what the compiler is doing is more complicated than the other forms of "sugar" you listed, but it's not doing anything special that you couldn't have done yourself that would be indistinguishable from what the compiler does (if you do it correctly).

Answer (score 7):

The compiler optimizes a `switch` statement based on string values using the `hashCode()` method, and then uses a lookup table in the bytecode. This is generally more efficient than an `if`-`else` statement.

For example, the following:

```
String string = "x";
switch(string) {
    case "x": System.out.println("x");
              break;
    case "y": System.out.println("y");
              break;
    case "z": System.out.println("z");
              break;
}
```

is transformed to this bytecode:

```
ldc "x"
astore_1
aload_1
astore_2
iconst_m1
istore_3
aload_2
invokevirtual java/lang/String/hashCode()I
tableswitch 120
  10
  17
  24
  default: 30
aload_2
ldc "x"
invokevirtual java/lang/String/equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
ifeq 30
iconst_0
istore_3
goto 30
aload_2
ldc "y"
invokevirtual java/lang/String/equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
ifeq 30
iconst_1
istore_3
goto 30
aload_2
ldc "z"
invokevirtual java/lang/String/equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
ifeq 30
iconst_2
istore_3
iload_3
tableswitch 0
  32
  36
  40
  default: 43
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
ldc "x"
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
goto 43
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
ldc "y"
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
goto 43
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
ldc "z"
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
return
```

Comment: Why would this be more efficient? A switch on essentially random keys cannot make use of a jump table. The jump table would need 2^32 entries in the worst case.

Comment: @usr Even if a jump table cannot be used, even if the switch ends up a series of if-else checks on an integer value, that is still generally less expensive than a series of if-else checks on a string value.